# How to insert into a static table using EXCEPT?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, except

I am developing an SSMS 2008 R2 T-sql query.  Currently my query looks like:

```
INSERT rd_scs_only_clients
SELECT DISTINCT en.clientid_c
FROM cd.enrollments en 
WHERE en.agency_c in ('SCCR','SCRP') AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), startdate_d) > 90
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT en.clientid_c
FROM cd.enrollments en 
WHERE en.agency_c not in ('SCCR','SCRP')
```

but this results in 0 records because it doesn't seem to be recognizing all of the code below the INSERT statement as belonging to the same query.  How can I rewrite this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wrap your statement in select * from and it should work.

```
INSERT rd_scs_only_clients

select * from (
SELECT DISTINCT en.clientid_c
FROM cd.enrollments en 
WHERE en.agency_c in ('SCCR','SCRP') AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), startdate_d) > 90
EXCEPT
SELECT DISTINCT en.clientid_c
FROM cd.enrollments en 
WHERE en.agency_c not in ('SCCR','SCRP')
)DATA
```

Comment: These are all great ideas and I think they all work!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
insert rd_scs_only_clients (yourclientfieldname)
Select * from
(
SELECT DISTINCT en.clientid_c 
FROM cd.enrollments en  
WHERE en.agency_c in ('SCCR','SCRP') AND DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), startdate_d) > 90 
EXCEPT 
SELECT DISTINCT en.clientid_c 
FROM cd.enrollments en  
WHERE en.agency_c not in ('SCCR','SCRP') 
)v
```

If that's not doesn't work, there may be a problem elsewhere. Try the SQL without the insert section

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way of doing this sort of thing is to select into a recovery table from the source table except the target table.

Although there is then the second-step of inserting into the target table everything from the recovery table.

That way you can back out (of either step) with confidence if needed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).